# ami_block_device_mappings not working properly with packer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, packer

I am using packer to create AMI adding 2 block devices, 1 root and another ebs attached to it. The block device mapping is not attaching the ebs block to the ami or temporary instance created.
My code block looks like (only details with block device mapping added):

```
"builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
       "ami_block_device_mappings":[{
        "device_name":"/dev/xvda",
        "volume_size":8,
        "volume_type":"gp2",
        "encrypted":false,
        "delete_on_termination":true
       },
       {
        "device_name":"/dev/sdb",
        "volume_size":50,
        "volume_type":"gp2",
        "encrypted":true,
        "delete_on_termination":true
       }]
     }],
      "provisioners": [
    {
        "type" : "shell",
        "inline" : [
            "sleep 30",
            "sudo yum update -y",
            "sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel",
            "sudo yum install ansible -y",
            "sleep 30",
            "sudo fdisk -l"
        ]
    }
  ]
```

fdisk -l shows that only 1 block added

```
 amazon-ebs: Disk /dev/xvda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
    amazon-ebs: #         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
    amazon-ebs: 1         4096     16777182      8G  Linux filesyste Linux
    amazon-ebs: 128         2048         4095      1M  BIOS boot parti BIOS Boot Partition
```

I am not sure why this would be happening? Any help on this?

Thanks and Regards,
Jay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `launch_block_device_mappings`.

Comment: Thanks Rickard. launch_block_device_mappings resolved the issue I was facing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you accept the answer everyone can see that this is resolved.